# Search for certain entries in an expression

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

I have a list with large expressions. I would like to find certain functions and their derivatives by searching the list. The search outcome should be the functions/derivatives found only, not the entire term or list element. For example, if a list element is the following:

```
3x1 F[x1, x2, x3] G[x1, x2] + x2 F^(1, 0, 1)[x1, x2, x3] + F[x1, x2, x3]
```

So if I search for `F`, I get

```
{F[x1, x2, x3], F^(1, 0, 1)[x1, x2, x3]}
```

and accordingly create a rule of association as follows:

```
{F[x1, x2, x3] -> g1, F^(1, 0, 1)[x1, x2, x3] -> g2}
```

Comment: Try this: `DeleteDuplicates[Cases[3 x1 F[x1, x2, x3] G[x1, x2] + x2 Derivative[1, 0, 1][F][x1, x2, x3] + F[x1, x2, x3], F[__] | Derivative[__][F][__], ∞]]`

Comment: That seems to work great. Thanks. I have added another bit to the question if you could please help with that and post it as an answer.

Comment: For creating the rules, use [Thread](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html).

Answer (score 1):

As @J.M. pointed out in the comments, you can use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) with [`Alternatives`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) to get each appearance of either form `F[__]` or `Derivative[__][F][__]`.  And together with `Thread` you can create a list of rules to be used as replacements.

```
termsearch[expr_, term_] := {#, Thread[# -> Array[g, Length@#]]}&@DeleteDuplicates@Cases[
  expr,
  (term[__] | Derivative[__][term][__]),
  ∞
]

termsearch[3 x1 F[x1, x2, x3] G[x1, x2] + x2 Derivative[1, 0, 1][F][x1, x2, x3] + F[x1, x2, x3], F]
```

> {{F[x1, x2, x3], Derivative[1, 0, 1][F][x1, x2, x3]}, {F[x1, x2, x3] -> g[1], Derivative[1, 0, 1][F][x1, x2, x3] -> g[2]}}

Or a method (if you don't really care about the numbering of `g` or there are no duplicates) where you create the rules when Cases finds each appearance

```
termsearch2[expr_, term_] := {#[[;; , 1]], #} &@DeleteDuplicatesBy[
  Block[
    {k = 1}, 
    Cases[expr,  f : (term[__] | Derivative[__][term][__]) :> (f -> g[k++]), ∞]
  ],
  First
]
termsearch2[3 x1 F[x1, x2, x3] G[x1, x2] + x2 Derivative[1, 0, 1][F][x1, x2, x3] + F[x1, x2, x3], F]
```

> {{F[x1, x2, x3], Derivative[1, 0, 1][F][x1, x2, x3]}, {F[x1, x2, x3] -> g[1], Derivative[1, 0, 1][F][x1, x2, x3] -> g[3]}}

**Example**

```
SetAttributes[p, Listable]
{a, b}.p[x, Range[0, 1]] + {c, d}.(p[x, Range[0, 1]] /. p -> p')
termsearch2[%, p]
```

> a p[x, 0] + b p[x, 1] + c Derivative[1][p][x, 0] + d Derivative[1][p][x, 1]
>
> {{p[x, 0], p[x, 1], Derivative[1][p][x, 0], 
>     Derivative[1][p][x, 1]}, {p[x, 0] -> g[1], p[x, 1] -> g[2], 
>     Derivative[1][p][x, 0] -> g[3], Derivative[1][p][x, 1] -> g[4]}}